# Traversable in Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to understand  the example from the `Data.Traversable` documentation.

```
 data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

instance Traversable Tree where
    traverse f Empty        = pure Empty
    traverse f (Leaf x)     = Leaf <$> f x -- confusion
```

How it is possible to apply `Leaf <$> f x`. `Leaf` is not a function and it is still possible to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaf is a function.

If you use GADT syntax this becomes immediately apparent:

```
data Tree a where
    Empty :: Tree a
    Leaf  :: a -> Tree a
    Node  :: Tree a -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

Answer (score 3):

`Leaf` is a constructor, thus a function. In this case it has type `a -> Tree a`. See [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor#Data_constructors_as_first_class_values).

Answer (score 3):

It helps to write `Tree` it in [`GADT`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-GADTs)[`Syntax`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-GADTSyntax):

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}

data Tree a where
  Empty :: Tree a
  Leaf  :: a -> Tree a
  Node  :: Tree a -> a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

which makes it clear that `Leaf :: a -> Tree a` is a function. We can be explicit about the kind of `Tree`,

```
import Data.Kind

data Tree :: Type -> Type where
  ..
```